# Does this line contain a function declaration?

Tags: javascript

The following line is known as a function expression in JavaScript. Does it contain within it a function declaration?

```
var foo = function() {};
```

Edit: edited for clarity.

Comment: Sorry, but that is not a duplicate. It is related, but not a duplicate.

Comment: Both are declaring functions and the difference is explained in the dup.  If you think your question is different than the dup , then edit your question and clarify what else you are asking.

Comment: @jfriend00 That may be so, but there is a lot of (uncorrected) misinformation in responses to that "dupe" too. "Function declaration" there is conflated with "function statement" throughout. Hence my confusion and this question.

Comment: So this whole question is about   spec terminology and not result? What is the actual objective of the question?

Comment: @jfriend00 Is understanding the terminology not an end in itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it does not. Both function expressions and function declarations do define functions, and contain the `function` keyword.

How they differ is basically determined where they appear in the source code, their syntax is otherwise the same. It is

- a *function expression* when it appears where an expression is expected, e.g. within the grouping operator or an assignment expression (as in your code)
- a *function declaration* when it appears directly in the body of a function, module, script (global code), or eval code. Since ES6, declarations can also appear as part of a StatementList, i.e. inside a block.
- a *function statement* when it appears where a statement is expected. Until ES6, this term was used to distinguish it from a declaration when the function syntax appeared in a block. If not inside a block, it is basically equivalent to a declaration.

Also read http://kangax.github.io/nfe/ which explain all these terms (pre-ES6 though).

For the difference between their evaluations see [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/q/336859/1048572).

Comment: OK I presume this is defined in the spec. Are function statements similarly well-defined (I'll hunt now)? Edit: it would appear not.

Comment: OK thanks very much. This is *much* clearer than the reams of high-voted answers elsewhere on here.

Comment: I am unable to find "function statement" in the ES5 spec... https://es5.github.io/#x12

Comment: @BenAston: Your question would've been answered by some of the lower-voted answers on that suggest duplicate, though. See the answers by CMS, thomasrutter and T.J.Crowder especially.

Comment: OK point taken, but when in a position of ignorance, teasing the information from the misinformation (or at least substantial ambiguity) is by definition impossible.

Comment: @jfriend00: I didn't mean that `var f = function() {}` is a function statement. That's an expression statement containing a function expression in an assignment expression of course.

Comment: @BenAston: Yes, "function statement" is not an ECMAScript term. I think it was dubbed by mozilla. See http://kangax.github.io/nfe/#function-statements for more information.

Comment: @BenAston For the origin of "function statement", see the "NOTE" at the bottom of [section 12 of ES5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12): "Several widely used implementations of ECMAScript are known to support the use of *FunctionDeclaration* as a *Statement*..."

Answer (score 3):

We can readily determine that this is not function declaration,
according to [ES5 section 14](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-14):

> - *Program* :
>
>   - *SourceElements<sub>opt</sub>*
> - *SourceElements* :
>
>   - *SourceElement*
>   - *SourceElements SourceElement*
> - *SourceElement* :
>
>   - *Statement*
>   - *FunctionDeclaration*

A *FunctionDeclaration* can only be a *SourceElement* (a quick search for *FunctionDeclaration* shows no other grammatical use), and a *SourceElement* can only be a top-level component of a list of *SourceElements* (either a *Program* or a *FunctionBody*). This use of `function` is nested inside of an assignment, so it cannot be a top-level *SourceElement*.

Furthermore, we can also rule out this as a *FunctionDeclaration* by [its definition](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13):

> - *FunctionDeclaration* :
>
>   - `function` *Identifier* `(` *FormalParameterList<sub>opt</sub>* `)` `{` *FunctionBody* `}`

Your code does not have an *Identifier*, which is mandatory for *FunctionDefinitions* (but optional for *FunctionExpressions*).

Comment: "We can readily determine that this is not function expression" - you mean function statement

Comment: @BenAston What a typo. `D:` I indeed meant "declaration" not "expression". Fixed.

Comment: Oh ok I thought you meant statement. Both would be correct in light of my new understanding.

Answer (score 1):

A Function Expression defines a function but does not declare a function. As such the code

```
var foo = function() {};
```

defines a function and then assigns it to a variable.

Where as

```
function foo() {};
```

defines a function and declares it without the need for an assignment.