# What is the difference between function declaration Vs. definition in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function

There are examples here with C++ and Java but it'll be great if someone can explain this with JavaScript examples. Also how is definition Vs. declaration works for variables.

Comment: https://kangax.github.io/nfe/

Comment: @Kyll If I am not wrong that question is about difference between function declaration Vs. expression. Whereas I am looking for clarification between declaration Vs. definition (not expression).... assuming there is any.

Comment: We call both function *declarations* and *expressions* a "function definition", and both variable *declarations* and *initialisations* a "variable definition". It's not a standardised term, though.

Comment: Unlike C, Javascript has no notion of function declarations as distinct from definitions.

Comment: To add some context... At about 2:20 on this video https://youtu.be/KRm-h6vcpxs?t=2m8s the author makes this statement... "Parentheses around the function that causes the parser to treat it not as a function declaration but as a definition". Hence my curiosity if there is any difference between declaration Vs. definition? @Bergi

Comment: @Adi: In that case, it's a mistake and he meant "expression". That's even what the text says on the slide - twice.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi - now I can move on with my life :)

Answer (score 3):

There is no notion of "*function definitions*" in JavaScript. It does only distinguish between [*function declarations* and *function expressions*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/336859/1048572) (and the deprecated [*function statements*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29522104/1048572)).

When we use the term "definition", it's typically meant as a hyperonym for both.

It's similar for variables: there's only the term *variable declaration* in the standard, and when we use "variable definition" we either refer to that or the initialisation of the variable with a value (or both).